# client service reference not working ToArray

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to fix this problem with my client
I got the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'DentistServiceReference.Dentist[]' to 'DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient[]'

Here is the code:

```
private List<DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient> DentistDetail()
{
    DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient client = new 
    DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient();

    DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient[] dentists = client.DentistDetail();  <== error

    return dentists.ToList();
```

I also tried to change the client.DentistDetail().ToArray  but still have an error.

Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient[]'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I went under App_WebReferences, right click Add Service Reference, Discover choose my DentistService.svc, go to Advanced tab and under Collection Type: System.Array,  Should I change it to system.collections.generic.list ?    I saw also System.Collections.ArrayList can you explain me what are the difference and what will be resolve my problem ?   Thanks a lot

Here is the DentistService.cs

```
 public class DentistService : IDentistService
 {
 /*   public List<Dentist>  DentistDetail()    */    use to be like this before the change
    public List<DentistServiceReference.Dentist> DentistDetail()
    {
        using (DentistDataContext db = new DentistDataContext())
        {
            return (from dentist in db.Dentists

                select new  Dentist()    
                {
                    Id = dentist.Id,
                    Dentist_name = dentist.Dentist_name
                }).ToList();     <=== error after the change
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `ToArray()` (note the parentheses)?

Comment: What is the return type of `client.DentistDetail()`?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` - it was created before generic as an "easy" way to add objects to a collection.

Comment: client.DentistDetail().ToArray()   same error Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'DentistServiceReference.Dentist[]' to 'DentistServiceReference.DentistServiceClient[]'

Comment: @ D Stanley  when I go to the DentistService1.xsd I got this <xs:element name="ArrayOfDentist" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayODentist" />   i will think it is a type of array.

Comment: @D Stanley how to convert to a T0List() if I want to populate a dropdownList ?